# NGINX and Laravel - json post request with special characters

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have an issue with my nginx and laravel app. Every time nginx forward the request to laravel app the payload with special characters becomes blank even the headers of the request are correct. Below is the sample payload:

```
{
"request": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Féminine"
  }
}
```

and headers of this request are:

```
 {
    "content-type":["application\/json; charset=utf-8"],
    "cache-control":["no-cache"],
    "host":["127.0.0.1:7004"],
    "connection":["keep-alive"],
    "content-length":["40"]
}
```

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: what special characters  your sending and what your getting ?

Comment: I think the characters like `é` are not valid characters for JSON payloads and should be escaped as `\u00E9`.

Comment: The payloads are coming from 3rd party services so I don't have control over it. Is there a way or any config on my nginx to forward the payloads with special characters to my laravel app?